# Why are only the first four alternating groups are non-simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, intuition

I know asking for intuition in math is a generally flawed approach, but can anyone give any reason why only the first four alternating groups are non-simple?

Comment: The first thing to say is that this is not true: $A_0, A_1$ and $A_2$ are all the trivial group, which is not simple.

Comment: The first half of your sentence lost me. *Most* of math is intuition driven in the sense that it revolves around ideas. That said, after the ideas take on a life of their own, things *can* get very unintuitive. Still, it is a weird mistake to give up on intuition in mathematics :P

Comment: @ChrisEagle Without trying to sound like I'm preaching: it's probably pretty frustrating for inexperienced students to be smacked down with a niggle. Rather than posting "your question is wrong because of edge cases," could you consider converting that comment to "You probably want to edit that to exclude these edge cases".

Comment: Okay, so left me see if I understand. Because the first are trivial, they are not simple? Then all greater than three still are? I edited the question.

Comment: why is intuition in math flawed?

Comment: @Khromonkey That's what I've been told by proffesors. The fact I'm asking this question shows I don't believe it.

Comment: as the quote goes "The nice thing about intuition is that you can adjust it in light of the facts".

Comment: It's [too simple to be simple](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best exercise for you would be to go carefully examine a proof of the fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq5$.

In a nutshell, you will find that 5 symbols is the minimum necessary to pull tricks to show that $A_n$ is simple. For $A_3$, there is simply no room for proper normal subgroups. For $A_4$, there are just enough symbols to have a subgroup, but too few symbols available to keep it from being normal. So, $A_4$ just happens to have the Klein 4-group as a normal subgroup.

Because of the added variety in the 5+ symbol groups, it is always possible to show that a normal subgroup contains a 3-cycle, and hence (by a lemma you will probably see in your book) is the entire alternating subgroup.

Comment: Dear Rschwieb, In you fourth line, you probably mean "proper subgroups" (since having no proper *normal* subgroups is the hallmark of being simple).  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Yes, it's a hallmark that $A_3$ has, so I don't see where the sentence is problematic. The goal was to explain why $A_4$ is at a balance point where a proper normal subgroup slips in, but is not eliminated. I think we're reading the sentence with two different angles, that's all.

Comment: Dear rschwieb, I see; thanks!  Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

Actually $A_0,A_1,A_2$ are trivial and $A_3\cong C_3$ is simple, so you're really just asking about $A_4$.

Let $V_n$ be the set of all permutations on $n$ letters of the form $(2)(2)$ - i.e. all products of $2$-cycles.  We can quickly see that $V_n$ is stable under conjugation because cycle conjugation preserves cycle type.  Thus $\langle V_n \rangle$ is always a normal subgroup of $A_n$. (*Note*. For a broader way to see that $V_n$ is normal, indeed *characteristic*, in $A_n$, see the EDIT of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217614/12952).)

There are exactly three elements of type $(2)(2)$ which can be made from $4$ letters: $$V_4 = \{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}.$$  We can easily verify that $V_4$ (along with the identity) is closed, so $\langle V_4 \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ of order $4$.

For $n\geq 5$, however, this doesn't work because $V_n$ *generates* $A_n$ and thus is not proper.  This alone is not enough to prove that $A_n$ is not simple, but it is enough to suggest it intuitively.  Sylow theory finishes the job.

Comment: "Sylow theory finishes the job" Would you mind elaborating? I have not seen a single proof of simplicity of $A_n$ which would use Sylow theorems.