# Automorphism of a symmetric group, except fot $n = 6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

How can I prove that all automorphisms of a symmetric group $S_n = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ are inner automorphism except for $n = 6$? I saw some related questions in the forum, but couldn't understand them yet.

And is this exception only applicable to $6$? Is it possible to construct an outer automorphism for it?

I first tried to prove it in a general way, hoping that somewhere along I would have to make an exception for $n = 6$, but that didn't work...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123413/outer-automorphisms-of-s-6

Comment: The key is to prove that the conjugates of transpositions are transpositions. Unless $n=6$ no other conjugacy classes of involutions have the same number of elements as the set of transpositions.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258824) for a proof when $n \ne 6$.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the outer automorphism understand that there are 6 conjugates of the nontrivial $S_5$ living in $S_6$. Use the Elliott Configuration for example https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/outer-automorphism-of-s6/

And then consider the action of $S_6$ on those conjugates, this gives the outer automorphism.